# Why can not the constructor be found - cyclic dependency

Tags: c++

Why it is okay when define `op_and* operator&(data& left, data& right)` in `op.h`

```
/* data.h */
#ifndef _DATA_H
#define _DATA_H
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "node.h"
#include "op.h"

struct data: node{
    std::string name;
    int width;
};

#endif //_DATA_H

/* op.h */
#ifndef _OP_H
#define _OP_H
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "node.h"
#include "data.h"

struct op: node {
    const std::string symbol;
    explicit op(data& left, data& right, std::string symbol):
    node(left, NODES::EMPTY, right), symbol(std::move(symbol)){}
};

struct op_and: op{
    explicit op_and(data& left, data& right):
    op(left, right, "&"){}
};

op_and* operator&(data& left, data& right){
    return new op_and(left, right); // it is okay here
}
#endif //_OP_H
```

But when define it `data.h`, IDE hints `No matching constructor for initialization of "op_and"`?

```
/* data.h */
#ifndef _DATA_H
#define _DATA_H
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "node.h"
#include "op.h"

struct data: node{
    std::string name;
    int width;
};

op_and* operator&(data& left, data& right){
    return new op_and(left, right); // here is error, cannot find op_and(data&, data&)
}

#endif //_DATA_H
```

This does look like a Circular dependency problem. I made a mistake. When I tried to include `op.h` in `data.h`, I get something like:

```
#ifndef _DATA_H
#define _DATA_H

#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "node.h"

#ifndef _OP_H
#define _OP_H

/* including "op.h" starts */
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "node.h"
#include "data.h" // this will introduce nothing because _DATA_H is already defined

struct op: node {
public:
    const std::string symbol;
    symbol(std::move(symbol)){}
    explicit op(data& left, data& right, std::string symbol): // symbol "data" has not been declared yet
            node(left, NODES::EMPTY, right), symbol(std::move(symbol)){}
};

struct op_and: op{
public:
    explicit op_and(data& left, data& right): // symbol "data" has not been declared yet
            op(left, right, "&"){}
};

#endif //_OP_H
/* including "op.h" ends */

struct data: node{
    std::string name;
    int width;
};

op_and* operator&(data& left, data& right){
    return new op_and(left, right); // error
}

#endif //_DATA_H
```

Now, definitions of `struct op`, `struct op_and`, and method `operator&` are in-valid since symbol `data` has not been declared.
So, if I put `#include "op.h"` after the definition of `struct node`, things work fine.

```
#ifndef _DATA_H
#define _DATA_H

#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include "node.h"

struct data: node{
    std::string name;
    int width;
};

#include "op.h"

op_and* operator&(data& left, data& right){
    return new op_and(left, right);
}

#endif //_DATA_H
```

Comment: Circular dependency. data .h needs op.h. op.h needs data.h. Which comes first? Same again with node.h and everybody else.

Comment: Side note: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/4581301) Breaking these rules doesn't bite all that often, but when it does bite, you come away looking like the poor lady out night swimming at the beginning of Jaws.

Comment: I misread. There is no node.h. Wonder what I was smoking.